# c# and HtmlAgilityPack: get value of a href attribute

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Using vs 2019 and .net 4.8, the c# code below get for following html node and I'm having trouble getting the href value.
The href attribute has a full url but the only text I'm getting is "/".

Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong and how to get the full url text?

Thank you.

The node:

```
<h2 class="n">
3. 
<a class="business-name" href="/santa-monica-ca/mip/specialists-in-custom-software-16438720" data-analytics="{&quot;target&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;feature_click&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" rel="" data-impressed="1">
<span>Specialists In Custom Software</span>
</a>
</h2>
```

My code:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=custom+software&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA");

HtmlNode[] nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2 [@class='n']").ToArray();
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectNodes("//a//span").First().InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectNodes("//a").First().Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it, although I didn't understand why it doesn't work the way it is:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument document = web.Load("https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=custom+software&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA");
    
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2 [@class='n']");
    
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("a/span").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("a").Attributes["href"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dtoZGl

Comment: The only real difference was the xpath "//a" to "a".

Comment: OK that worked, Thank you.  Odd, all the examples I see online use double forward slashes.

Comment: Yeah, double slashes are supposed to search recursively through children while single slash will search first level children... it was supposed to work regardless, that's the weird part.